# Ubuntu 14.04 bad taint on XFS and BTRFS

Tags: 14.04, btrfs, xfs

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on a physical machine and a virtual machine and after the first reboot (and also at random times) on the screen I get a bad taint message for XFS and BTRFS modules.

I don't currently have any XFS or BTRFS FS's but would like to.

Can someone tell me what this means, if it is safe to use the system like this, and if there is a way to stop these error messages?

Comment: Please add more details alike errors output etc.

Comment: Did something change these kernel modules on your system? Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some Oracle software installed. Or something around. If your fresh install was merged to old home it might be some old Oracle configuration file with large data filesystems support. Ubuntu did not shipping natively these filesystems and that suggested to the user installs foremost with reliably ext3/ext4.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it. I have a fresh install of 14.04 server and it's doing this too.

Comment: Please add more details alike errors output etc.