# Ubuntu 14.04 bad taint

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, oracle, btrfs, xfs

Any body got the solution for the below question? please share it. I couldn't add comment ,so i created new question here.
[Ubuntu 14.04 bad taint on XFS and BTRFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465099/ubuntu-14-04-bad-taint-on-xfs-and-btrfs)

Problem:

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Dell R610 server. It is a fresh installation (Of-course previously windows server was installed, I have erased the data and deleted the partition and recreated it). While installing Ubuntu server I selected openSSH and SAMBA file share to install. After installation I have  installed Virtual box 4.3 and phpvirtualbox 4.3. Everything work fine. But after restarting the server I got this error messages ( just one time I got this).

1. xfs: module has bad taint, not creating trace events
2. btrfs: module has bad taint, not creating trace events

Please help me to fix this error.

I am noob to Ubuntu. Also I am not getting this error now (I haven't done anything). But Do I need to worry about this error in future?

Thanks in advance.
Bharath

Comment: What file system did you install Ubuntu on? You should use `ext4` wherever possible, as that's its native file system. It might not be able to correctly boot from others (as your current wording suggests you can't boot because of these errors).

Comment: I have used ext4 file system only while creating partitions in Ubuntu. I am able to reboot it now without any error. I am just wondering what caused this issue and how to prevent it in future? As I pointed out the other question, the error may appear randomly. So I am scared to go ahead with my other work on this server now.

Comment: I haven't had XFS work in Ubuntu since Warty Warthog. But Butter FS is coming out of experimental, and moving into stable. try: $`sudo apt-get purge intel-linux-graphics-installer && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @j0h I will give it a try, But right now the error is not showing up, so I can not confirm whether it resolves this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @j0h I got this after executing your command **E: Unable to locate package intel-linux-graphics-installer**